# ribbon binding ribbon to ServerIntrospectorConfig

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-ribbon

After i have migrated my application from spring boot 1.5.6 to 2.1.3 it is giving me the following Error

```
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'ribbon' to org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.ServerIntrospectorProperties:

Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.ServerIntrospectorProperties]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Please some one suggest me the solution for that